# What is the impulse response of the system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, signal-processing

Given this input-output system what is the impulse response

()/*dt* + () = (),  ≥ 0, (0) = 0

I used an integrating factor to find y(t)

*y(t)* = ${\int t*x(t) *e^tdt\over e^t }$

From here i thought I should use the replace x(t) with an impulse, but  I'm not sure of what the limits should be for the integral. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What should the limits of the integral be in the numerator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you multiply by the integrating factor you get
$$
(e^t\,y)'=t\,e^t\,x
$$
Integrate betwwen $0$ and $t$ to get
$$
e^t\,y(t)-y(0)=\int_0^ts\,e^s\,x(s)\,ds
$$
and
$$
y(t)=e^{-t}\int_0^ts\,e^s\,x(s)\,ds.
$$

Comment: I don't understand why I should integrate between 0 and t.

Comment: $t=0$ is the starting time at which you have the initial condition $y(0)=0$. And $t$ is the time at which you want the solution.

Comment: ok that makes sense...now to find the impulse response simply make the input a delayed delta function?